# Unable to start service in Android

Tags: java, android

I made I widget for reading news-items. If I put one widget at my homescreen, everything is fine. But if I put a seconde one at my homescreen and I remove it, the service of the widget stops. So if the widget gets in the update methode, an error occurs.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service news.WidgetActivity$UpdateService@405231d8 with Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=news/.WidgetActivity$UpdateService bnds=[26,97][79,151] }: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

A nullpointer is at this line:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
```

Here the code:

```
public static class UpdateService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.WidgetRefresh_btn, View.GONE);
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.progressWidget, View.VISIBLE);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);

        WidgetActivity.Widget.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `context` object is probably null. Since you are in a service, which extends `Context`, you may as well use `this.getPackageName()` or just `getPackageName()` instead.

Comment: Tnx! Hhn.. think that the problem is fixt. But now I have another problem: If I have two widgets and I press on a button on the first one, the seconde widget updates hiszelf. Does this have anything to do with the WidgetIdd?

Comment: That depends on the intent that you set to your first widget. If it triggers the update mechanism of your appwidgets, it may update the second one. But its hard to tell without the whole update code. If you can't figure it out i recommend opening a new question. The id is only a unique reference to each appwidget instance. Should not be assigned to both widgets, so i'd guess it has nothing to do with it.